# Including a term as random intercept and random slope in mixed model

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am fitting a mixed model of crop yield against rainfall collected over multiple years and locations. Usually in the agriculture domain, there is a strong time trend i.e. increase in yield with time because of changes in technology. I specified my model like this:

```
 mdl <- lmer(yield ~ rainfall + (1|year) + (1|location), data = dat)
```

However, if I understand the above specification correctly, it assumes that same time trend exists across all locations which is not correct. So if I want to include a term which allows the time trend to change dependent on location, which of the following specifications is correct:

```
mdl <- lmer(yield ~ rainfall + (1 + year|year) + (1|location), data = dat)
mdl <- lmer(yield ~ rainfall + (1|year) + (1 + year|location), data = dat)
```

Comment: How many years do you have? How many locations?

Comment: what do you understand by time trend to change dependent on location, The location is a fixed factor ? can it cause  any change in crop yield ?

Comment: Time trend is dependent on location because some locations will have more improvement in irrigation and adoption of improved varieties compared to other locations.

Comment: I have 2000 locations and for each location I have 15 years of data

Comment: Two last models in your question do not make sense (either of them). You need a fixed effect of `year`, allowing for quadratic or cubic dependency, and a random effect of `year` depending on `location`. I.e. something like `yield ~ rainfall + year + (year | location)`, but you should extend this to a more flexible dependency on year.